# How to Fetch date and time from a formatted string in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, date, xcode6

I have a NSString "dateString" which contains date and time in given format.

`"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"`.

I want to fetch the data from the dateString using `NSDateFormatter` and then I'm trying to show in a String `"strDate"`. I.m able to fetch the data but the only issue is that i'm not getting the correct value  for `"hour"` place.

For Ex:

```
dateString   = 1/23/2015 7:06:37 AM
strDate   = 01/23/2015 00:06:37 am
```

How to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance. This is my code:

```
-(NSString *)getDateQuestion:(NSString *)dateString
{
NSLog(@"dateString   = %@",dateString);

//NSString to NSDate
NSDate          *datefromString  = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter   = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+5:30"]];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

datefromString                   = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"dateString1   = %@",datefromString);

//NSDate convert to NSString
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+5:30"]];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSString       *strDate          = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datefromString];
NSLog(@"strDate   = %@",strDate);

return strDate;
}
```

Comment: When you print the date, do you set a time zone? NSDate has no time zone information.

Comment: Yes. I'm using time Zone "GMT". Can you suggest which time zone for india. as i'm using +5:30 for india.

Comment: Can you please post the code you use to convert the string to date and the date to string?

Comment: Help me plz .... Have i done something wrong ?

Comment: you have  to set one timezone `[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+5:30"]` or `systemTimeZone`

Comment: But , when i'm using only one time zone then I'm getting the same issue. second time zone was for just try..

Comment: Use UTC+5:30 and remove the repeated codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Pass Correct date Time string to the function and don't set time zone Unnecessary again and again... i hope it helps you...

```
NSDate *dat = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter   = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC+05:30"]];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];

NSString * dateString =[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dat];
NSLog(@"dateString   = %@",dateString);
NSLog(@"dateString1   = %@",dateString);

//NSDate convert to NSString
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss a"];

NSString       *strDate          = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dat];
NSLog(@"strDate   = %@",strDate);
```

HH stands for 24hr.

hh satnds for 12 hr.

Answer (score 1):

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

Replace with `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"`