# How to convert a string Date to NSDate in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate

I googled so many times, but I am not satisfied with given answer. Please anyone can give correct answer what I need.

This is the retrieve date string from DB : **2015-05-27 10:19 (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm)** 
I want to convert into `NSDate`.

My code is like Below:

```
 NSString *date_str = @"2015-05-27 10:19";
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
 NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:date_str];
 NSLog(@"date == %@",date);
```

But output is : date == **2015-05-27 04:49:00 +0000**

Its showing **04:49:00** time , but my retrieve time is **10:19**.

How can i retrieve perfect time from DB.

Please help out me..

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with the locale. Please try to add it like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964747/nsdateformatter-locale)

Comment: May be without NSTimeZone [http://stackoverflow.com/a/28644052/3177007] link helps you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert your date to GMT time like this:-

```
NSString *date_str = @"2015-05-27 10:19";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:gmt];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:date_str];
```

And the **output** is :-

```
date == 2015-05-27 10:19:00 +0000
```

---

And to **get the date without +0000**, you can store it in NSString directly:-

```
 NSString *s = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

**Output :-**

```
2015-05-27 10:19
```

Comment: Nice. its working fine :). But if i want to delete that +0000 ?

Comment: @SRNayak  its NSDate object description formate and saved into your database, whenever you want specific format from your NSDate object, again use the NSDateFormatter!

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the timezone issue with conversion, because server time and local timezone may have difference. So handle this you need to set the timezone to your dateformatter like

```
[dateFormater setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```